# Fijar caracteres dentro de un input

Tags: html, entrada, caracteres

Es posible que dentro de un `input` yo establezca unos caracteres fijos que no se puedan borrar?
Es decir, algo asi:

```
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

Donde las x son números que introduce la persona y los guiones (-) esten fijos y no se puedan borrar?
Que sea un solo input

Mil gracias de antemano por su respuesta!
:)

Comment: Esto podrias hacerlo con javascript

Comment: Te comento que si es posible utilizando Javascript Gabriela, si necesitas ayuda intenta realizar el código y si se te presenta un problema entonces puedes colocar tu duda para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Sí es posible, es una máscara y puedes hacerlo tu mismo o implementar algún plugin, por elemplo este de jquery:
http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/